# How to get user-specific settings in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, role, configuration, users

I have to collect some information of PostgreSQL roles.  One piece of information is whether the role has different settings than 'usual', usual meaning here default values for only a few parameters (eg. `log_statement`).

So far I have only one idea: loop over all the users and issue the commands

```
\c postgres username

SHOW log_statement;
```

and then process the output.

I am wondering whether there is a similar method like querying the `pg_settings` view, showing per-user settings?  I don't need to know session-specific differences, only those that are persisted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the role configuration by querying  [pg_catalog.pg_shadow](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/view-pg-shadow.html) or pg_catalog.pg_user, 
as the following:

**--Query pg_shadow**

```
francs=# select usename,useconfig from pg_shadow ;
   usename    |           useconfig           
--------------+-------------------------------
 postgres     | 
 user_a       | 
 user_b       | 
 skytf_select | {"search_path=skytf, public"}
 francs       | 
 dwetl        | 
 skytf        | 
(7 rows)

francs=# alter role francs  set log_statement='all';
ALTER ROLE

francs=# select usename,useconfig from pg_shadow ;
   usename    |           useconfig           
--------------+-------------------------------
 postgres     | 
 user_a       | 
 user_b       | 
 skytf_select | {"search_path=skytf, public"}
 rancs        | {log_statement=all}
 dwetl        | 
 skytf        | 
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I started browsing the source code and came to `pg_db_role_setting` which contains the data, but of course the views you mentioned are easier to use.

Comment: @dezso:  I find pg_db_role_setting is better  later, thanks .

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately `pg_shadow` does not show roles with no LOGIN privilege.

I find it more useful to use @dezso hint view in the following query:

```
SELECT coalesce(role.rolname, 'database wide') as role, 
       coalesce(db.datname, 'cluster wide') as database, 
       setconfig as what_changed
FROM pg_db_role_setting role_setting
LEFT JOIN pg_roles role ON role.oid = role_setting.setrole
LEFT JOIN pg_database db ON db.oid = role_setting.setdatabase;
```

As always, just add it to psqlrc file ([see doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html))

Comment: Or just type  **\drds** in psql console )